# Sending a tweet with an image attachment from a URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, bots, twitter-oauth

I'm making a Bot for Twitter use the 'twit' package for node that tweets out the News for a game from an endpoint whenever it changes, however I'm having problems actually sending an image from a url as a twitter attachment. Despite how simple that sounds there's virtually nothing I can find on how to do it and everything I do find both doesn't work and is extremely complicated.

I've tried getting the URL using request, converting it to base64, and using 'media/upload' to get an ID for the image and then send a tweet using that media_id however that still sends a tweet without an attachment or image.

```
        let b64;

        request.get('https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Fortnite%2Ffortnite-game%2Ftournaments%2FPlaylistTile_BetaTournament2-1024x512-438bf9615e13c058a69075c0e577af779d7e3aa8.png', function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                data = response.headers["content-type"] + new Buffer(body).toString('base64');
                b64 = data;
            }
        });

        T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64 }, uploaded);

        function uploaded(err, data, response) {
            var id = data.media_id_string;
            var tweet = {
                status: `News Update!\n${news.br[0].title}\n${news.br[0].body}`,
                media_ids: [id]
            }
            T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);
        }
```

I expect to send a tweet with an image from the URL as an attachment instead of just tweeting with the URL in the tweet.

Answer (score 0):

Node is asynchronous. That means this part:

```
T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64 }, uploaded);

function uploaded(err, data, response) {
    var id = data.media_id_string;
    var tweet = {
        status: `News Update!\n${news.br[0].title}\n${news.br[0].body}`,
            media_ids: [id]
        }
    T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);
}
```

will be executed immediately without waiting for the request to get the actual picture.